Question regarding symbol used in inverse trigonometry
I know this question must not be here, but I can't find any website which helps me with this
What is the meaning of-    $arc$ $\cos^2x$

Very likely $(\arccos(x))^2$, but it's hard to say without context or a reference.

In analysis, the typical meaning of $f^2(x)$ is $\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^2$. So, I am quite sure that $\arccos^2(x)$ is just $\big(\arccos(x)\bigr)^2$.
